# Strategies for tracking down the root cause of NullPointerExceptions in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, nullpointerexception

Are there are any accepted best practices/strategies in tracking down the root cause of `NullPointerException`s in Java, in particular when it comes to threading?

**The background:** I have a threaded app that uses Apache's `HttpClient` 4.2, and from time to time we see what seems to be a NullPointer occuring when we call the `HttpClient`'s execute method. ("What seems to be", as the returned value is just `null`.) I know all threads share the same `HttpClient` with the same `PoolingClientConnectionManager` (thanks to a `System.out.println(httpClient)`, printing out the references), but it seems like we still get thread-related errors in the library (probably due to something we did wrong). And while I would love to find a solution to that particular problem, I'm much more interested in general approaches to finding the root cause of `NullPointerException`s - as I said, *especially for threading*, and even more if the exception gets thrown deep *inside a library*.

Comment: I would say look at the error ?

Comment: Threading issues essentially boil down to: you have accessed a shared state (typically variable) without proper synchronization and when you use it / read its value you get an inappropriate result. So (i) find where the null value is originated, (ii) identify which variables are shared in the code producing the null value (iii) determine if there is a synchronization issue (I have skipped the obvious (0) make sure the code is otherwise correct in a single threaded environment)

Comment: The error can be less helpful than you imagine when a null is causes much earlier, passed around by assorted methods that are happy with nulls before finally finding something that cokes on it

Comment: Log the stacktraces. Once you get one, inspect the method backwards for non synchronized/volatile/final variables

Comment: A cause of NPE in httpclient i have seen was using a shared HttpContext for multiple Requests. if using httpcontexts, create a new one for each request.

Comment: Ideally nothing would ever throw a NullPointerException, if methods check if their input is null before using it, and throw an IllegalArgumentException instead it becomes *much* easier to find where the problem is occurring!

Comment: @Nick In theory, in a multithreaded environment, you could pass the non null test at the beginning of a method and still get a null later on in your method (if you have not used proper synchronization etc.).

Comment: "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work." such as reading the stack trace

Comment: @Raedwald: The exception gets thrown in a library used in a Java app that gets imported into a service. The framework this runs on does return exceptions at the service level, but the problem occurred 3 levels down, where I cannot access output easily and running the app locally w/o the platform does produce different results (as the service platform is responsible for spawning up threads). I don't have access to the service platform's source code, complicating things further. We pinned it down to the execute method sometimes returning null, and I thought I'd ask to determine what to do next.

Comment: @MarkusKull: in every thread's equivalent to the run method, we do this: `httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, new BasicHttpContext());` It's httpResponse that now sometimes holds `null`. `httpClient` is created in a thread-safe way and shared across all threads.

Comment: ""What seems to be", as the returned value is just null" so in fact, you do not have a NPE at all, but rather a method returning a null when you do not expect a null?

Comment: @Raedwald: You might have a point there. I did not run the last tests myself and was told we have a NullPointer, but what I just saw in our source code was a check if that line returns null. We did get unexplainable SocketExceptions that only occurred while running on the environment and under load. I will try to run the test again once the environment is back, to verify if there really is a NullPointerException... But then again, I was more interested in general strategies; our current problem was merely the reason I am interested in them...

Answer (score 2):

If a 3rd party library throws exceptions or converts them, you can attach [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) to a thread. [This](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2006/06/13/java-5-global-exception-handling/) also could be helpful.

**UPD:** Just a suggestion. Is it possible to replace standard java  exception class using a custom classloader?

Comment: If it swallows the exceptions, an UncaughtExceptionHandler won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you, Noofiz. Do you have any recommended reading (links) on using a classloader to do that?

Comment: No, sorry, that was just a suggestion.